# Is it possible to use third-party audio units in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/AudioUnitHostingFundamentals/AudioUnitHostingFundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH3-SW11):

> Note: The iOS dynamic plug-in architecture does not support
>   third-party audio units. That is, the only audio units available for
>   dynamic loading are those provided by the operating system.

I'd like to add distortion effect to my sound. And would like to explore the possibly of using a third-party audio unit to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: It is entirely possible to use it  if you have the source-code to use it.  If not - no chance whatsoever.

Comment: how would you do this marko? Specifically to to add distortion to a audio signals passing through an audio graph.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are answering your own question by quoting the documentation: no it is not possible.

It is, however, possible to write your own distortion effect. There are different kinds of distortion, the simplest being "clipping", which might look like this:

```
float THRESH = .5; //or whatever. Between 0 and 1.
float buffer[SIZE]; //defined elsewhere
for( i=0; i<SIZE; ++i ) {
    if( buffer[i] > THRESH )
        buffer[i] = THRESH;
    else if( buffer[i] < -THRESH )
        buffer[i] = -THRESH;
}
```

You might then want to follow that up with a low-pass filter to make it less harsh (you can use a built-in audio unit for that).

Comment: where would you add this code? in the context of using an audio graph.

Comment: You could use that code to create your own audio unit. You will have to read the apple docs to figure that out -- this is not an appropriate forum for providing a tutorial.